# Azure Bot Framework - MS Team integration - Voice capability

Tags: microsoft-teams, speech-to-text, azure-bot-service

I have an azure based chatbot and is successfully integrated with MS Teams. Currently it is supporting text chat only. I would like to enable voice chat (speech to text).
With Web chat, it is easily doable but with MS Teams, I am not able to find a direct way.

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Microsoft Teams channel don't support voice/speech, Webchat, Direct Line & Cortana channel do support speech. Teams have [calling and meeting bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) which allows to have IVR with Bots and there are [communications API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)